# With tls1_3 what do Kx=any and Au=any mean?

Tags: openssl

I am used to tls1_2 ciphersuites like

```
[evelden@gi2dpbvo00006 ~]$ openssl ciphers -v -s -tls1_2 -stdname 'EECDH+AESGCM'
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

So in the name of the suite I see the key exchange and authentication algorithms at the front and openssl explicitely tells them by means of the Kx and Au attibutes.

But with tls1_3 it goes like,

```
[evelden@gi2dpbvo00006 ~]$ openssl ciphers -v -s -tls1_3 -stdname -ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

So in the ciphersuite name I don't see the key exchange and authentication algorithms any more and the Kx and Au attributes are 'any'.

So what does any mean? Also there are always a key exchange and authentication algorithm. So what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TLSv1.3 the key exchange and authentication algorithms are negotiated separately to the ciphersuite via the key_share/supported_groups and signature_algorithms extensions. So you cannot tell just by looking at the ciphersuite what key exchange/authentication algorithm will be used - this is why OpenSSL just reports them as "any".

See RFC8446 sections 4.2.3, 4.2.7 and 4.2.8.